# Windows Azure Powershell command Get-AzureWebsite results in error String was not recognized as a valid Boolean

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to manage some of my Azure Services via Powershell, using http://windowsazurewebsitescheatsheet.info/#powershell as a starting point.  I was able to download and import my subscription settings just fine (Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile and Select-AzureSubscription)

After choosing my subscription, I'm attempting to run the Get-AzureWebsite command to view all of my websites, and continue onward from there.  When I run that command, however, I get the following:

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile "C:\AzureCredentials.publishsettings"
Select-AzureSubscription "My Azure Subscription"
Get-AzureWebsite

Get-AzureWebsite : String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureWebsite
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureWebsite], FormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.GetAzureWebsiteCommand
```

Anyone have similar issues?  I get this error if I run the command as stated above, or if I specify the name of my website.  TIA for any help!

Comment: Can you provide a little more information from your script? Copy-paste couple line where you call Get-AzureWebsite cmdlet

Comment: Thanks @sha, just updated

Comment: Try to run get-help Get-AzureWebsite to see the description of various parameters - may be you have different version then I am. Also - are you able to run any other Azure cmdlets on this subscription?

Comment: Thanks, for syntax I got "Get-AzureWebsite [[-Name] <String>] [<CommonParameters>]".  I downloaded Azure Tools from Platform Installer yesterday, which was version 0.7.2, released on Dec 10 2013.. so maybe its a bug?

Comment: @sha, I didn't implement git on my website, is git required to communicate with this command?

Comment: git should not be required. And version looks fine. Are you able to run any other Azure cmdlets on your subscription?

Comment: Get-AzureEnvironment and Get-AzureLocation both work, along with the Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile and Select-AzureSubscription commands I'm initially running, it's just an issue when I try to get my websites it seems...

Comment: I have the same problem, but not for every Subscription! 
`PS C:\> Select-AzureSubscription "B*****s"`
`PS C:\> Get-AzureWebsite`
`Get-AzureWebsite : String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.`
`At line:1 char:1`
[snip!]
`PS C:\> Select-AzureSubscription "Z******a"`
`PS C:\> Get-AzureWebsite`

`Name       : ******`
`State      : Running`
`Host Names : {******************.azurewebsites.net}`

Comment: In my case it does not matter how many website are running under a subscription. Get-AzureWebsite works fine for Subscriptions with either one or two sites, but fails for one particular Subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be related to a known issue enumerating a sites with SSL bindings
There was  new release of Windows Azure Powershell released on 02/12. Please try with the new  version.

Comment: That worked, thanks @Richard!  Grabbed the latest tools from http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/downloads/, and I can now connect to my websites via PowerShell.. thanks much

Answer (score 0):

Please run the command again with -Debug turned on, this will display request and response messages and make it easier to pinpoint the issue.